# redirect with javascript and analytics

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can track a link from an email with google analytics.

In the email there is a link to a pdf ebook confirmation page. In need to track that, so when a person click the link to the ebook, I need to take the URL parameters, and redirect with javascript to the confirmation page, after google analytics have registrered the tracking.

But how can I take the URL parameters and redirect with javascript? Is it something to do with `window.location`?

Comment: No need for JavaScript, you just create a custom URL with analytics and it will register the tracking. So its ends like something like this: `http://yourwebsite.com/ebook/confirmation?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ebookdownload`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. What if I said that my boss said I HAD to do it with javascript.... :-/ Do you have a clue on how I could do it?

Comment: Maybe because you need to have the JavaScript analytics script in the confirmation page, I took that for granted.

Comment: Yes that should also be there. Hm I have to look more on google to see if I can find something. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make sense to want this, if the destination URL was to a static PDF file that would be served directly by the HTTP server (no application involved).  For example, `http://example.com/ebook.pdf`.  Since the PDF is a static file, there is no way to inject the Google Analytics (GA) Javascript code to register the page view.  To track the click in the email link using UTM codes and register the page view with GA, you would need an intermediate page that contains your GA javascript and pageView call and then use Javascript to redirect to the static PDF URL.

The code to this intermediate page would be something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Insert your Google Analytics code here; this must come first -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ebook_url = "http://example.com/ebook.pdf";
    window.location = ebook_url; // redirect happens here
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

Let's assume that intermediate redirect page is served at `http://example.com/ebook/confirmation`.  In the email you would add the UTM codes to that URL link, like @yuriy636 suggested: `http://yourwebsite.com/ebook/confirmation?ut‌​m_medium=email&utm_c‌​ampaign=ebookdownloa‌​d`

Comment: Thank you a lot. It really sounds like what my boss was talking about. Just really hard to describe something, when you are not understanding it correctly. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: perfect perfect I am so happy

Comment: I just followed this threat here. So this line of code should go on the confirmation page, or?

Comment: @NeKr, you're welcome.  If my understanding of your problem is accurate and the solution does work, you might consider editing your question to better explain the actual problem, so others with the same problem can more easily find this.

Comment: @BillDoughty are you still active here?